# What makes the Breeder's Diary a future diary in Mirai Nikki?

Tags: mirai-nikki

I only found out that the diary allowed Tenth to control the dogs, but that wouldn't make the diary a future diary. So he had to be able to see some kind of future events with it.

Does anyone know what he saw with it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Tsukishima couldn't control the dogs with the diary, but used voice commands via a cell phone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

His diary allowed him to not just control the dogs but also to **know their future**. That's why he could be one of the players of the diary game. The following is written in the [the wiki](http://futurediary.wikia.com/wiki/Karyuudo_Tsukishima#Diary_.26_Abilities):

> His diary is The Breeder Diary, which is mostly used by his daughter
>   Hinata. Despite of this its uses are clear, which involves to predict
>   the movements of his dogs and those of his targets.